# Twitter bootstrap columns resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a layout with two columns, and in the first column I have sub columns. So something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span1"></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span1"></div>
      <div class="span1"></div>
      <div class="span1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
  </div>
</div>
```

When the page is resized to be smaller, I would like the two outer columns to stack on top of each other, but not the inner columns as they always need to be on the same line i.e. once the page is resized below the width of the span8 it then introduces a horizontal scroll bar.

Is this possible?

Comment: you will have to write your own custom `css` and add your own `classes` because within the bootstrap, all `span#` get set to `width: 100%`

Comment: thanks mate, was kind of assuming i might have to but just thought i'd see if anyone knew a hidden secret! here's a little jsfiddle to demonstrate what you said, when you resize all the spans go to `width: 100%` - http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1966/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8 container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span1 offset2"></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span1"></div>
      <div class="span1"></div>
      <div class="span1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you use a fluid layout inside of span8, the content in it should stay on the same line.

And, I don't know if you're aware, but a row is always 12 columns, even if it's in a span8.

I hope you know what I mean. Sorry for my bad english.